# Uploading app to appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, apple-push-notifications

I have created an app which using APNS. I have got the push notifications when I used developer certificate and its working fine. I installed it through Adhoc method. Now I need to upload my app to appstore. I build my app with distribution certificate and put the same in the server also, but not getting any notifications. This is my first time i am doing this. I have went through so many forums and I got so many situations. One is, the token ID (i think it is the same as device token) should be different in development and production mode, but I am getting same token ID. But still I am not sure about the issue. 
So I have some questions, which certificate should i use in my app and at the server when uploading to appstore? And should I use Sandbox or production server?
Please give me a clear idea about all these.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox certificate is used for development, the production certificate is used for apps submitted the AppStore. The correct certificate is linked to either the development provisioning profile or the distribution (AppStore) provisioning profile.

The one thing to remember is to recreate the provisioning profiles if you create the push certificates *AFTER* creating the original profile. The profiles should contain and 'aps-environment' string if push is enabled for your app, otherwise push won't work. If your app initially didn't contain push (this functionality -including certificates- were added at some later point), then the provisioning profiles for both development and the AppStore will not contain the 'aps-environment' string and thus push won't work.

You can open your profiles in a text editor and look for the 'aps-environment' string to make sure it exists. This was the main issue with push I kept running into, so my guess is you have run into this as well.

Recreation of profiles is easy, just open them up on the Apple Developer portal, change some setting and save. Download and install the new profile to use it.

---

**Edit:** Well, I got push working with an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. First I recommend you download the following project from github, it's really convenient for testing development and production push:

https://github.com/Zambiorix/Apple-Push-Notification-Test

Next I'd like to know if you're able to debug the app. If you're able to debug the app, then you're not using the Ad-Hoc profile. When you try to debug with the Ad-Hoc profile, the app will start followed by a crash (some message involving *get-task-allow*).

Comment: i checked that and it contains <key>aps-environment</key> string.

Comment: did you actually upload the app to the AppStore yet?

Comment: not yet, before that I am testing it with the distribution certificates for pushnotification.

Comment: I believe you can only "see" the distribution certificate work once your app is published on the AppStore. **Edit:** from what I've read the distribution certificate can also be tested with Ad-Hoc builds.

Comment: yes, now I am trying through Adhoc method, using distribution certificates. That should work right?

Comment: and one more, I have distribution_identity.cer and production_identity.cer and adhoc.mobileprovision certificate. Which combination I am supposed to use? Now I am using adhoc.mobileprovision certificate with distribution_identity.cer. Is that right? If yes what is the purpose for production_identity.cer?

Comment: Today I'm going to try it myself (use production push with AdHoc cert & profile) since I just discovered AdHoc can be used for production push. I'll let you know if I can get it to work and the steps I've taken.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried for push notification with the app that you said. and i got notification with Sandbox enabled but i haven't got when the sandbox disabled.

Comment: i am not sure about how to debug the app. Now I am using Distribution build and installing it through addhoc method through itunes.

Comment: yes, this is the log 2012-02-01 13:44:21.509 Apple Push Notification Test[4275:903] Socket GW : Push to : b4855437 8a9f460f 172bf575 975ed9e9 f3a1d458 69847bf8 cf5e532b f5f2d2e0
2012-02-01 13:44:24.221 Apple Push Notification Test[4275:903] Socket GW : Error : Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9829 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9829.)"
2012-02-01 13:44:24.223 Apple Push Notification Test[4275:903] Socket GW : Terminated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7226/discussion-between-wolfgang-schreurs-and-john)

Answer (score 2):

All the above stuff mentioned by `Wolfgang Schreurs` and in addition to that please make sure when you are testing push notification for adhoc bundle you use

`ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

**instead of**

`ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

As apple uses production identifier for AdHoc profiles too, following will be the details in adhoc/distribution profile if you open it with text editor.

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>something.com.yourappname</string>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>                      <--Notice This
```

and if you check for development profile it would be something like,

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>something.com.yourappname</string>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>development</string>                     <--Notice This
```

Comment: yes, this is in my profile <key>Entitlements</key>
 <dict>
  <key>application-identifier</key>
  <string>something.com.myappname</string>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>production</string>
  <key>get-task-allow</key>
  <false/>

Comment: To send notification which url you use ? Do you use PHP or .Net based code ?

Comment: i am using gateway.push.apple.com and .Net based. Now let me check with the link that you have mentioned.

Comment: and one more, I have distribution_identity.cer and production_identity.cer and adhoc.mobileprovision certificate. Which combination I am supposed to use? Now I am using adhoc.mobileprovision certificate with distribution_identity.cer. Is that right? If yes what is the purpose for production_identity.cer?

Comment: In one of our previous project we used https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS this code of dotnet to send push notification. Its very simple to use and we just need to pass .p12 file exported from keychain.

Comment: we used that before, but it wasn't supporting our local language.